# Get current month as number in Pascal

Tags: time, pascal, lazarus

I've got an assignment to do which involves seeing if there are any birthdays this month. I'm not asking for you to 'do my homework', but what I *am* asking is this: is there a way to get the current month as a number from 1-12 in Pascal (specifically, Lazarus Pascal)? Then I can take the number and compare it with records held in file.

Thanks for any help,

James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about Lazarus, but most Pascal implementations provide:

```
procedure GetDate(var Year, Month, Day, DayofWeek: Word);
```

Comment: Yeah I saw that on my travels around the interblag. What I don't get is how to actually use it :-P

Comment: var  y, m, d, dow : word;   begin GetDate (y, m, d, dow);  writeln ('The current date is ', y : 1, '-', m : 1, '-', d : 1, ' and the numbered day of week is ', 'dow:1);end;

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
DecodeDate(Date:TDateTime, Year, Month, Day: word);
```

I recommend you to check dateutils unit. It provides full support for all "date" or "time" issues.

Answer (score 1):

Manny is right. I just tried it in Lazarus, by writing this procedure:

```
procedure Dates;
var y, m, d: word;
begin
  DecodeDate(Date, y, m, d);
end;
```

Date is a function in SysUtils (datih.inc) that returns the current local date. DecodeDate is a procedure that takes a TDateTime and returns to var parameters the calendar values of year. month and day. You need all 3 of course, but just use the one you need.